# Movie where the characters finds out what they have to do right at the moment they need to do it to avoid the enemy knowing their plan

Tags: story-identification, movie, telepathy

I remember watching a movie quite a few years ago (probably 2010-2015) where the enemy/bad guy (might've been a lot of enemies I don't remember) of a group of people could read minds or something similar so he knew what they were planning to do. In order to confuse him, one of them, which I think was the male protagonist, came up with a plan that he wrote cards with plans on what to do and they only opened them up in specific times to find out what the plan was, so their plans kept on changing and the enemy couldn't know their whole plan beforehand... Does anyone know which movie that could've been?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: The idea of being given instructions to get through a sticky situation (often a heist of some kind) with amnesia seems quite common. In addition to the Doctor Who episode _Time Heist_, I'd mention Colin Kapp's book [_The Patterns Of Chaos_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Patterns_of_Chaos), the 1990 movie [_Total Recall_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/), Philip K. Dick's novelette [_Paycheck_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_(novelette)), the second radio series and book of _The Hitch-Hiker's Guide To The Galaxy_…

Comment: …and many other works listed on the TVTropes page [_Note To Self_](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoteToSelf) (TVTropes warning!!).

Comment: Since P.K. Dick was mentioned, his novel [Solar_Lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Lottery) deals with confounding telepaths by switching plans randomly. He used a similar concept in [The_Game-Players_of_Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game-Players_of_Titan) where a character is drugged so that reading his mind gives unreliable information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Push (2009 film)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_(2009_film)

Knowing that both Division and Triad Watchers can see their every move, Nick proposes an elaborate plan to obtain the drug and eliminate their enemies. He creates several envelopes containing instructions for each of his friends, including the Shifter called Hook Waters and the Sniff called Emily Wu. Nick seals each envelope and gives them to his friends before hiring the Wiper who erased Kira's memory to do the same to him. With his memory wiped, the Watchers are unable to see his future, enabling the group to execute Nick's plan.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Possibly [Time Heist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Heist), an episode of the TV show *Doctor Who*.  It's the correct period (September 2014) and similar plot.

> In Clara's flat, the Twelfth Doctor answers the TARDIS's phone; both are surprised to find themselves in a room with two others: Psi, a hacker with an augmented brain, and Saibra, a mutant shapeshifter. A recording includes messages from each agreeing to a short-term memory wipe, before getting instructions from the Architect to break into the Bank of Karabraxos and steal three items from its vault.
>
> The head of bank security Ms. Delphox uses a telepathic alien called the Teller to detect those with criminal intent and destroy their brains; the Doctor believes the memory wipes were needed to avoid being caught.

Comment: Nope. It's not the one I was talking about, although it's very similar to the one I remember and I do love doctor who, so I've watched it :D